# Iterate through rows, look for matching characters with matching indexes, and if this is true: put a '1' in another column - R

Tags: r, regex, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I want to loop through 'standard' & 'superficial.match' and get two bits of additional data:

1) does 'standard' have a character that shares the same value and same index as a character in 'superficial.match' ('mips' = matching in place)

2) how many characters in 'standard' match with characters in 'superficial.match' ('two.match')

for example:

in row 1, there is a matching 4 in the third-place, and there are two 4's in 'standard' so 'mips' and '2match' should = True or 1

in row 6, 4 matches in place, but there is only 1 match, so 'mips' = True and 'two.match' = False

```r
> head.matrix(masterdata[c(5,6,14,15)], n=6)
  standard superficial.match mips two.match
1      464               584    0      0
2      575               159    0      0
3      686               896    0      0
4      131               971    0      0
5      818               348    0      0
6      242               348    0      0
```

row 3 seems to have 1 character that matches in place and 1 that does not, this should be an 'NA' for 'mips'

Answer (score 0):

If you split each of the fields `standard` and `superficial.match` to obtain vectors of their component characters, you can then compare each pair with the usual `==` operator.

I'm assuming that these fields are strings, not numeric.

This function does the split, checks if the number of places in which matches occurs is greater than 0, and then, for every character that matches, checks how many times it occurs in the `standard` column to return a boolean if the number of matches >= 2.

```
fn <- function(x) {
  x1 <- unlist(strsplit(x[1], ''))
  x2 <- unlist(strsplit(x[2], ''))
  cmp <- x1 == x2
  mips <- sum(cmp) > 0
  if (mips) {
    two.match <- max(rowSums(outer(x1[cmp], x1, FUN = '=='))) >= 2  
  } else {
    two.match <- FALSE
  }

  c(mips = mips, two.match = two.match)
}
```

You can run it row-by-row on the matrix `x`, and transpose to get into columnar format:

```
t(apply(x, 1, fn))
      mips two.match
[1,]  TRUE      TRUE
[2,] FALSE     FALSE
[3,]  TRUE      TRUE
[4,]  TRUE      TRUE
[5,]  TRUE      TRUE
[6,]  TRUE     FALSE
```